# FluentWait throwing "The method until in the type Wait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments" error

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating test case. I want to use FluentWait but it is throwing "The method until(Function) in the type Wait is not applicable for the arguments (new Function(){})" error.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).
                withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
               wait.until(new Function< WebElement, Boolean >() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebElement element) {
                return element.getText().contains(employeeFirstName);
            }
        });
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with package. Are you importing the correct package- import com.google.common.base.Function;

Comment: the issue was with `new` invocation of the `method until` of type `wait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("my-css-selector")).getText().contains("name");
  }
});
```

Comment: Link not found unfortunately.. When I try to copy this code, it asks me to remove @Override notation.

Comment: I removed link from the answer − it's 2 years old!

Comment: Can you give me another reference, please?

Comment: Ask new question.

Answer (score 3):

add this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the other method implementation:

```
withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
```

The form `withTimeout(Duration timeOut)`
is still used and non-deprecated one

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `WebDriverWait` instead of `FluentWait` and it worked for me.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 60);
wait.withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        WebElement ele=driver.findElement(locator);
        if(ele==null)
            return false;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("found");
            return true;
        }     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void clicon(WebDriver driver,WebElement locator,Duration timeout)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    locator.click();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].